# Functions Arrangement in C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, function, visual-c++

I am just starting out with C++ and I have some problems arranging the functions.

When I was using Unity (C#), I used to first write the Start function and then other functions based on the time they will be called in.

But here, in C++, it looks like it's vice versa !

For example, I wrote this simple program while learning on LearnCPP.com

```
#include <iostream>


void Add(int No1, int No2)
{
    std::cout << No1 + No2 << std::endl;
}

void Subtract(int No1, int No2)
{
    std::cout << No1 - No2 << std::endl;
}

void GetNumbers(int Operation)
{
    int No1;
    int No2;

    std::cout << "The first no. : ";
    std::cin >> No1;
    std::cout << "The second no. : ";
    std::cin >> No2;

    if (Operation == 1)
    {
        Add(No1, No2);
    }
    else if (Operation == 2)
    {
        Subtract(No1, No2);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int Operation;
        int TryAgain;

        std::cout << "Enter 1 for an Addition Operation. Enter 2 for a Subtraction Operation." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> Operation;

        GetNumbers(Operation);

        std::cout << "Enter 1 to try again. Enter 2 to exit.";
        std::cin >> TryAgain;

        if (TryAgain == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (TryAgain == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I was going to write it in C#, I would first write the main (Start) function then GetNumbers and then Add and Subtract functions.

If I write it in C++ this way, I get errors (I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition).

Is there any way I can do it ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: You can [forward declare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) the functions and then define their body after the `main` function

Comment: @twentylemon while it's often helpful to know the errors one is receiving, this is a rare case where the problem is so simple that looking at the code should easily show you the issue (which, as a new-to-C++ programmer, the OP is just not familiar with).

Comment: @mah everything is declared before it is used...

Comment: @twentylemon Yes, and when he changes this, he gets errors. The code he posted is a working example. Reread the question.

Comment: @twentylemon his question seems to be that if he writes it in the posted order it's fine but he would rather change the order (to be consistent with how he would have written it in `C#`). It's not quite clear the way he phrased things, but that's the take-away I received from it.

Comment: This actually answers a question of mine: Why are so many people defining main at the top and its support beneath. WARNING! If you go with the forward definition as opposed to defining the function ahead of it's first use, you now have an extra change to make if you need to alter the function's signature. If you miss one, you'll have linker errors if you are lucky. If you aren't lucky, you'll get bizzaro storms of error messages or something that almost works. And then doesn't.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers @twentylemon and all of you (I can't tag anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Functions must be declared before you use them, but you can define them later:

```
int add (int a, int b);

int main () {
    return add(1,2);
}

int add (int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because C++ needs a function header to know what parameters the function uses before it's called so you either have to define them before you call them in main or declare function prototypes like so :

```
#include <iostream>


//function prototypes
void Add(int No1, int No2);
void Subtract(int No1, int No2);
void GetNumbers(int Operation);

int main ()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int Operation;
        int TryAgain;

        std::cout << "Enter 1 for an Addition Operation. Enter 2 for a Subtraction Operation." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> Operation;

        GetNumbers(Operation);

        std::cout << "Enter 1 to try again. Enter 2 to exit.";
        std::cin >> TryAgain;

        if (TryAgain == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (TryAgain == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void Add(int No1, int No2)
{
    std::cout << No1 + No2 << std::endl;
}

void Subtract(int No1, int No2)
{
    std::cout << No1 - No2 << std::endl;
}

void GetNumbers(int Operation)
{
    int No1;
    int No2;

    std::cout << "The first no. : ";
    std::cin >> No1;
    std::cout << "The second no. : ";
    std::cin >> No2;

    if (Operation == 1)
    {
        Add(No1, No2);
    }
    else if (Operation == 2)
    {
        Subtract(No1, No2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: @AdhamT Please accept an answer with the green V if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be at least forward declaring functions, and probably using .hpp files containing the forward declarations.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ we mostly work with scopes , that said as long as a variable or function has not been declared extern or declared previously (header ,etc) the compiler cannot tell.

Comment: I think this answer is a little confusing to the target audience. Maybe you could expand on it a bit and connect how it relates to the question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: What you can is to create a macro and insert it at the end of cpp files , make an output then you will know if a class has been read from the compiler. Forward declaration at the beginning of headers , includes in the beginning of cpp files. That should help .

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, C++ works just like C#, if you compare apples to apples. The similar to C# example would include a class with some members that you can define and call in any order:

```
class CMyClass
{
    void Start()
    {
        GetNumbers(1);
    }
    void GetNumbers(int Operation) 
    {
        Add(2, 3);
        Subtract(4, 5);
    }
    void Add(int No1, int No2) {}
    void Subtract(int No1, int No2) {}
};
```